# luxon get local date string with GMT from YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: luxon

I am using [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) for my app. I have simple date string like this `2022-02-10` and I want to convert them into `Thu Feb 10 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`. But don't know how to do it in [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/).

```js
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");

const date = "2022-02-10";

const dateTimeWithGMT = DateTime.fromISO(date);

console.log(dateTimeWithGMT);

// expected output

// Thu Feb 10 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired format seem to be the one returned by JavaScript Date [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString), so you can simply convert luxon's DateTime object to native JavaScript Date using [`toJSDate()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetojsdate)

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

const date = "2022-02-10";
const dateTimeWithGMT = DateTime.fromISO(date);
console.log(dateTimeWithGMT.toJSDate().toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

[Formatting](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting) section of the docs properly describes how to format Luxon DateTime objects. Luxon supports ISO 8601 formats (see [`toISO()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoiso)), human readable formats (see [`toLocaleString`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetolocalestring)) and custom formats (see [`toFormat`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoformat))